# Can't click elements below div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a simple menu with css and jquery. It works great but when I open it  I can't click the elements below.

https://jsfiddle.net/tano4xv1/

```
<header> 
<nav>
    <span>
        <img src="img/header.png" alt="logo">
        <i class="fas fa-bars trigger">menu</i>
    </span>
    <span class="menu-container hidden">
        <div class="menu">
            <a href="#">option</a>
            <a href="#">option</a>
            <a href="#">option</a>
            <a href="#">option</a>
        </div>
    </span>
</nav>
```

```
<p><a href="#">Option I can't click</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Option I can't click</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Option I can't click</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Option I can't click</a></p>
```

JQUERY is basically a class toggle to move between the div positions

```
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const trigger = document.querySelector('.trigger');

function toggle() {
  menu.classList.toggle('menu--open');
}

trigger.addEventListener('click', toggle);
```

My css. The animation was made with pure CSS. I'm moving the div when click the menu button.

```
.menu {
  position: relative;
  top: -300px;
  transition: 0.3s all;
}

.menu--open {
  top: 0;
 transition: 0.3s all;
}

nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
}

nav span {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

nav span:nth-child(1) {
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
}

 .menu-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.fa-bars {
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.fa-bars:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

span .menu {
    background: #95baa8;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
}

span .menu a {
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Those options are hidden under the `<nav>` tag. That element has a z-index of 1 and absolute positioning, so it is essentially sitting on top of the first two links

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself.

Comment: `edit ` your question: click on the `<>` icon. Then you can paste your full code in a "snippet". It works just link jsfiddle, but runs locally and is embedded in the question. This makes it easier for users and they'll be more inclined to help you. Also if jsfiddle were to become unreachable, the question would be useless to future visitors, degrading the quality of SO. Also It's policy to include an MVE in (most) questions. In the Help center you can read about "How to create a Minimum Viable Example" for future reference. It's fine to *also* have a link to js fiddle if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links are actually being "covered" by the header. You can use the [CSS property](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) `pointer-events: none` to get through that. This has been answered [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4839672/5758451)

Comment: Setting the a elements in `pointer-events:auto` and the menu container in `pointer-events:none` fix it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replate the `span` items with the `div`. 
https://jsfiddle.net/ug28sbkr/